# Unity - Adding new variables to binary formatted save data?

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, binary, save, load

I use binary formatter to save user data which includes a bunch of nested classes and parameters. When I need to add new parameters to any class, game loads with corrupted data/no data at all for users coming from the previous version.

I tried null check new variables after load, and copy from default data if its null but its not the fix. The game doesn't crash but all prices and levels from user data is lost.

```
public void Load()
{
    GameData = new GameDataModel();

    if (File.Exists(GameFilePath + "/" + GameFileName))
    {
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        var file = File.Open(GameFilePath + "/" + GameFileName, FileMode.Open);
        var gameData = (GameDataModel)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gameData.WorldName))
        {
            GameData = CreateDefaultGameData();
        }
        else
        {
            GameData = gameData;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        GameData = CreateDefaultGameData();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < GameData.Cities.Count; i++)
    {
        if (GameData.Cities[i].FoodStall == null)
            GameData.Cities[i].FoodStall = CreateDefaultGameData().Cities[i].FoodStall;
        if (GameData.Cities[i].Billboard == null)
            GameData.Cities[i].Billboard = CreateDefaultGameData().Cities[i].Billboard;
        if (GameData.Cities[i].Trees == null)
            GameData.Cities[i].Trees = CreateDefaultGameData().Cities[i].Trees;
        if (GameData.Cities[i].Decorations == null)
            GameData.Cities[i].Decorations = CreateDefaultGameData().Cities[i].Decorations;
        if (GameData.Cities[i].Station.StationBuildingTypeCosts == null)
            GameData.Cities[i].Station.StationBuildingTypeCosts = CreateDefaultGameData().Cities[i].Station.StationBuildingTypeCosts;
        if (GameData.Cities[i].Station.StationBuildingType == 0)
            GameData.Cities[i].Station.StationBuildingTypeCosts = CreateDefaultGameData().Cities[i].Station.StationBuildingTypeCosts;
        if (GameData.Cities[i].Station.CapacityMultiplier == 0)
            GameData.Cities[i].Station.CapacityMultiplier = 1;
        if (GameData.Cities[i].People.DensityMultiplier == 0)
            GameData.Cities[i].People.DensityMultiplier = 1;
        if (GameData.Cities[i].Bus.ProfitMultiplier == 0)
            GameData.Cities[i].Bus.ProfitMultiplier = 1;

        GameData.Cities[i].Station.Parameters = DefaultGameData.Cities[i].Station.Parameters;
        GameData.Cities[i].Bus.Parameters = DefaultGameData.Cities[i].Bus.Parameters;
        GameData.Cities[i].People.Parameters = DefaultGameData.Cities[i].People.Parameters;
    }
}
```

I expect users from the previous version keep their data, and have new variables' default data. How would you handle adding new data to an existing serialized data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use a save format value

By knowing what version of the save file you have, you can easily determine whether or not to attempt to decode a given value or not.

If you don't have one, add one. Otherwise you're going to have to do this:

```
public static void deserialize(ref SerializationInfo info, ref StreamingContext context) {
    SerializationInfoEnumerator infoEnum = info.GetEnumerator();
    Hashtable values = new Hashtable();
    while(infoEnum.MoveNext()) {
        SerializationEntry val = infoEnum.Current;
        values.Add(val.Name, val.Value);
    }
    ...
}
```

And then use the hashtable to determine if a given value exists or not.

If you use a save version you can read it out first and then query it to see what should happen: read the value out of the binary data or set it to a default value. Which is [way, way easier](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/game/PlayerInfo.cs#L484-L489).

Comment: Thanks, but my game is already on the AppStore. Do you have any suggestions for existing method, how to add new variables?

Comment: Are you implementing ISerializable or are you relying on the default implementation of the BinaryFormatter? If the later, you're screwed.

Comment: i use default implementation. I tried many many things. I brought back the old class type that was in previous version. But deserialization still fails. I think i have to give up on existing users(maybe give them a kickstart) and change the saving system.

Comment: Deserialization will always fail if you change what fields a serialized class has, all the time, every time, unless you (in some way) manage the serialization yourself. There's no way around it, because the data is encoded with no metadata.